# custom-made lightbox cannot cover several parts of page

Tags: css, html, openlayers, image-gallery

I try to make a lightbox of my own.
I use a `div` to cover the web page and display in that `div` the images, buttons etc.

This div has a semi-transparent background image to "dim" everything.

The problem is that three things cannot be dimed. (they overlap the image)

-An openlayers map (inside html5's `article`)

-An html5 `video` tag

-An html5 `details` tag

This happens cross-browser.

Any ideas? Has to do with html5? The place/order the tags have in the DOM or something?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is the code. Hope it helps. Comes from a 2200 lines file, so its edited. Ask me if you want more specifications

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
//create image element to later append to lightbox div
var elem2 = document.createElement("img");

//open layers - set map...
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', options);
//more openlayers things here

//image takes its source from an array came form a query
elem2.src=mpli[0];

//then, append to the light box div
document.getElementById("lightbox").appendChild(elem2); 

//functions for hide/show the lightbox div
function lightboxme(){
        document.getElementById("lightbox").style.display="block";

    }

    function unlightboxme(){
        document.getElementById("lightbox").style.display="none";
    }

</script>


//map's article
<article id='map_element' style='width: 900px; height: 400px;'>
</article>


//the small div that contains the image gallery - when clicked , shows the lightbox
 <div id="smallbox" onClick="lightboxme();" ></div>

//the lightbox's div
 <div id="lightbox"    style="display:none ;"  >

//lightbox's css
        #lightbox {
    position:fixed; /* keeps the lightbox window in the current viewport */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(semi-transparent.gif) repeat;
    text-align:center;

}
```

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira Of? CSS? Or Javascript?

Comment: of what you have? so it can be replicated? or even better, make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of it

Comment: Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LNkHC/) sound about right? If not, feel free to make your changes

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira Here you go [link](http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/LNkHC/1/). But I think its hard to replicate the whole thing. Can jsfiddle recreate an openLayers map ?Thats why I am asking if it has to do with indexing div or something.

Comment: Do you have a link to your example? Without something to work on, its really hard to help ;)

Comment: You can include external resources on jsfiddle on the left btw

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira Sorry for taking some time to anser. I was searching. Turns out I can solve this just by setting the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). Thanks for your time